Circular modal logic question: Does it makes sense to ask if it is possible for the set of possible worlds to be empty?
I'm exploring the logical (im)possibility of nothingness. When thinking modally, I realized that there is an interesting "metamodal" phrase you can write about the set of possible worlds (W):

◇(W=∅)

This is basically asking if it's possible that the set of worlds is empty.
My first thought is that this must evaluate to false:

◇(W=∅) ⊨ ⊥

The reason being that the possiblity operator can only be true if there is at least one possible world where the predicate is true but if there are no worlds then the operator is vacuously false due to lack of any worlds.
However, this implies the truth of the dual:

¬ [◇(W=∅)] ⇔ □[¬(W=∅)]

So it implies that it is necessary that the set of possible worlds cannot be empty.
I feel like I've made a mistake somewhere but it's an interesting result of applying modal reasoning to one of the great questions of philosophy:

Why is there something rather than nothing?

Does anyone see an error here?

Re your "if there are no worlds then the operator is vacuously false due to lack of any worlds" sounds problematic, it may not be vacuously false but a possible state of affairs, see Kripke semantics: A Kripke frame or modal frame is a pair ⟨W,R⟩, where W is a (possibly empty) set...

@DoubleKnot is if W empty then the relation R produces no worlds where a predicate is true? that sounds like "not possible"..

Re your "the relation R produces no worlds", R is simply a binary relation over the Cartesian product of W with itself, not producing W or any world in W. If W=∅, then R=∅ trivially, but there's no trivial falsity here. Even for classical FOL, some prefer a nonstandard empty domain by default for statement convenience, especially for mathematicians with some algebraic model-theoretic structures in mind...

@DoubleKnot I think that if a predicate P doesn't hold in any worlds specified by R then the statement "It is possible that P" is false. This seems no different than the case where the accessibility relation yields possible worlds but P is false in all of them.

The set of possible worlds W is a semantic notion with respect to the modal language you are using. Therefore, you cannot write a sentence with W in that language, it is not in its syntax. If you want to use second order modality in meta-language you'll have to separately interpret what that means. And, in any case, the set of second order possible worlds W' will be something completely different from W (each element of W' is itself a set of first order possible worlds), so W = ∅ does not mean W' = ∅.

@Conifold makes sense - thank you!

From your comments and your accepted answer it seems possible that you're still confused about the root cause of your problem here in the sense that whether it's really the lack of your intuition about the possible existence of an underlying free/inclusive logic or really your misuse of meta-language's mentioned semantics into the object modal language in a liar-like self-referential way or both?...

@DoubleKnot — I think I was abusing the meta language with the object language ;-P

You are attempting to use modal operators within your metalanguage, which is a very odd thing to do. Usually we use modal operators to extend the object language.
It does not make much sense to speak of the set of possible worlds being empty. If there are no possible worlds then there is no actual world and hence there is nothing at all including you and me.
Modal logic requires an underlying logic and the default choice for this is either classical propositional logic or, if you are more adventurous, first order classical logic with identity. The issue here is that classical logic includes a built-in assumption that the domain is non-empty. So if you wish to describe the logic of states of affairs in which nothing exists then you need to use a different logic, such as one of the free logics.
If you wish to reason about situations in which some things do actually exist, but there is a possibility that nothing exists then you have at least a couple of options. You might try a modal extension to a free logic. Or you could use a classical modal logic in which some accessible worlds have empty domains. This modal logic would have to be non-normal since those worlds are impossible.

One thing I wanted to understand: if we have an accessibility relation R and predicate P it’s does make sense to ask “is it possible P”. Now if we have a situation where there are no accessible worlds such that P then “it is possible P” is false. It seems that this is totally OK in modal logic.

Therefore, by analogy, if there is no possible world such that P then “it is possible P” is false.

But that is exactly the case I was considering: if there are no possible worlds, then my formula is false due to lack of worlds, if there worlds then it is false because there are worlds. Either way it’s false and modal logic (meta logic?) applied to this seems to suggest there must be a possible world.

Perhaps the issue is that I haven’t defined the semantics of my metamodal logic

At the object language level, if there are no possible worlds then there are no possibilities at all. To write ◇(W=ø) is to say, in the metalanguage, that there is some object language with a non-empty set of PWs. I'm not sure why you would want modal logic in your metalanguage. It would be like saying you think there are many (possibly infinitely many) object languages with their own logic and you think there are interesting things to say about the relationships between them. It's best to have a simple metalanguage: arguably classical logic is the natural choice for the metalanguage.
